# c# Copy Object Group from Excel to PowerPoint

Tags: c#, excel, powerpoint

I have an object group (named 'Group 5') that contain chart (named 'Chart 1') and image (named 'Picture 3), and I would like to copy this object group from Excel to Powerpoint.

Previously I have Chart in Excel only and I know how to copy and paste to powerpoint by using below code.

```
// Get the ChartObjects collection for the sheet.
chartObjects = (Excel.ChartObjects)(xlWorkSheetTemplateChart.ChartObjects(paramMissing));

// Get the chart to copy.
existingChartObject = (Excel.ChartObject)(chartObjects.Item("Chart 1"));

// Copy the chart from the Excel worksheet to the clipboard.
existingChartObject.Copy();    

Thread.Sleep(1500);
// Paste the chart into the PowerPoint presentation.
shapeRange = pptPresentation.Slides.Range(IntialSlideCount).Shapes.Paste();
```

But when come to group the chart with the image, the above code will hit error and then I do not know how to write the code in C#. Please help.

Comment: We are all poor in guessing: The error code is....???

Comment: When you work with groups or Groupshapes you have to use the [groupshapes collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff195331.aspx) Your code deals only with Chartobjects, no GroupShpaes

Comment: The first time i changed the chart name to "Group 5" and it hit error "The item with the specified name wasn't found."

After that I tried other method by putting Shape.Range(Array("Chart 1","Picture 3")) and still not working. Getting error "Non invocable member Shape.range[object] cannot be used like a method".

do you have the code in C#? i checked from google, a lot of it are VB...

Comment: Puh where to start: Your chartobjects collection does not have a member called "Group 5", to be shure you have to scan through the collection. But your main problem is that you define an apple, but later you say its now a pear. This will not work! Forget for the first moment to translate it to C#, you have first to understand what you want. For me is your problem still unclear

Comment: My initial intention is just to copy the chart (Chart 1) from excel and paste to powerpoint. And so I am using ChartObjects. But later on, I need to group a Picture together with the chart and then only copy from excel and paste to powerpoint. I knew that the ChartObjects is no longer can be used for object grouping. But I tried around to write it in C# but cannot get it done. I have even tried to record the macro and look into the VBA code, and try to call the similar thing also not working.

Comment: Maybe you noticed that Powerpoint has no macro recorder. The reason is, it never worked really. But the object model is very helpful and has short snipplets where you could understand how it works (see my links). From my point of view you have two choices: 
1) ungroup the chart and picture and continue as you started
2) Try to use Groupshapes collection as I mentioned in my second post

Comment: I tried few times still unable to build the app successfully, and I have to change another solution. Thanks anyway for the advice! :)

Answer (score 0):

groups are shape. you can find them in sheet.Shapes.Item(i); ...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).